# How can i move Revision information to an existing tab on the node edit page?

Tags: nodes

I'm using Drupal 7. I know how to hide Revision information on the node edit page, but could they somehow be form_altered to have it's contents in another tab (group), which is defined in the content type? I'd like to have nice and clean tabs on the edit pages, and i already have an "Advanced" tab - there's no reason to have an own tab for revisions with only one field.

EDIT: Solved by form_altering the following lines:

```
$form['revision_information']['#group'] = 'group_advanced';
$form['#group_children']['revision_information'] = 'group_advanced';
$form['#fieldgroups']['group_advanced']->children[] = 'revision_information';
```

Just change "group_advanced" to the machine name to which you want to move the revision information to, and it should work! However, this moves the whole revision fieldset inside the custom tab, instead of just the fields... I'm sure that could be done too, but i'm happy enough with this solution too.

I still can't understand why it has to be this difficult, instead of just drag & drop in the content type settings...

Comment: How have you created the Advanced Tab? Is that a fieldset?

Comment: Yes, the Advanced tab is a custom Vertical tab created by me, and it has a few normal fields which I've put there. It shows similarly as the Revision information tab on all node edit pages, but is obviously constructed very differently from the $form variable.

Comment: You would need to create a module and use form_alter function to get the form you want to edit and then modify it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that was my starting point and my point was to ask how it should be done. However, I think i figured it out, the form_alter modification is edited to the original question for anyone having the same problem.